# Download all image or create zip file of all uploads from the gallary contained uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am on the photo sharing site , and i want to give functionality to download all the images available in the gallery ,, I have taken gallery in a relation where i can get all the iamges by @gallery.uploads ,

Now what i want is to download this all files , or if its possible to create any zipfile so that we can download that one file containing uploads inside the gallery ,

thanks

Answer (score 8):

Use the `rubyzip` [gem](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipFile.html) in order to create zipfiles on the server-side:

```
   require 'zip/zip'

   Zip::ZipFile.open("my.zip", Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) {
    |zipfile|
    puts zipfile.read("first.txt")
    zipfile.remove("first.txt")
   }
```

Add the images to the zipfile and use `sendfile` in the rails-application to send the files to the browser. Read the documentation on `Zip::Zipfile` and `sendfile` for the missing bits.

Comment: and how can i add images inside it? will you please elaborate your answer sir ?

Comment: That depends on how the images are stored on the server. Does `@gallery.uploads` return the image-data or just a path to the file?

Comment: hum i got the way to download by temp file ,whch creates tmp file ,put image files , and create on clien side with send_file 
thanks